# Laurent expansion of $\exp(z+\frac 1z)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, laurent-series

This question is similar to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1003267/what-is-the-laurent-series-of-exp-frac1z-exp-2z), but I want to explicitly calculate the Laurent series for the function
$$f(z)=\exp\left (z+\frac 1z\right)$$
around $z=0$, i.e. find a closed form for the coefficients $b_n$ of the expression
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}b_nz^n$$
Using the usual series for $\exp(\cdot)$, 
$$
\begin{align}
\exp\left(z+\frac 1z\right) &=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\left(z+\frac 1 z\right)^n}{n!}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{\binom n k z^kz^{k-n}}{n!}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}z^{2k-n}
\\&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}z^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!(n-k)!}z^{2k}
\end{align}
$$

Forgetting about coefficients, the $z$ terms in the sum indexed by $k$ are of the kind
$$1+z^2+z^4+\ldots +z^{2n}$$
and when multiplied by $z^{-n}$ are symmetric, becoming of the kind
$$z^{-n}+z^{-n+2}+z^{-n+4}+\ldots+z^n \tag 1$$
It seems like from this we can reconstruct each coefficient.

Let's try to understand what the coefficient for $z^0$ should be; clearly only even $n$ contribute to this coefficient since $z^{2k-n}$ always has odd exponent for odd $n$. If $n$ is even, the only term which has $0$ exponent in $(1)$ is the central one, i.e. the coefficient of $z^0$ is 
$$\sum_{n=0: \text{ n is even}}^\infty \frac{1}{\left(\frac n2\right)!\left(\frac n2\right)!}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!k!}$$

Playing a bit with the coefficients, I conjecture that a closed form for $(b_n)_{n\in \mathbb Z}$ is

> $$b_n=b_{-n}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{1}{k!(n+k)!}$$

I have two questions:

1. Can my argument for the calculation of $b_0$ be generalized to yield a closed form for $b_n$?
2. Is the conjectured closed form for $b_n$ correct? How can we find a closed form for $b_n$?

Comment: I guess you would be interested in the keyword [*'modified Bessel function of the first kind'*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html).

Comment: See http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselI/11/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An equivalent but a more straightforward way is to expand each exponential separately. Let us exploit the convention that $1/k! = 0$ for $k = -1, -2, \cdots$. (This convention is simply to forget about the pesky bounds for summation indices.) Then

\begin{align*}
e^{z+1/z}
= e^z e^{1/z}
&= \left( \sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^j}{j!} \right)\left( \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^{-k}}{k!} \right) \\
&= \sum_{j,k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^{j-k}}{j!k!} \\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{z^n}{(k+n)!k!},
\end{align*}

where $n = j-k$ in the last equality. Also, rearranging the sums works since they converge absolutely whenever $z \neq 0$. From this we read out that

$$ b_n = b_{-n} = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k!(k+n)!} $$

when $n \geq 0$.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you very much Sangchul.

Comment: @Lonidard, In fact your solution is just one step away from this derivation. Half of your computation is used to establish the identity $e^{z+1/z} = e^z e^{1/z}$ in disguise.

Comment: Indeed. I remember going over something similar in my first Calculus course proving $e^{x+y}=e^xe^y$ from the series definition.

Answer (score 1):

$$\displaystyle e^{z + 1/z} = \sum_{k =-\infty}^\infty \sum_{m  =-\infty}^\infty \frac{z^k1_{k \ge 0}}{k!} \frac{z^{-m}1_{m \ge 0}}{m!} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty  \sum_{k =-\infty}^\infty \frac{z^k1_{k \ge 0}}{k!}\frac{z^{n-k}1_{k-n \ge 0}}{(k-n)!}\\ = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty z^n \sum_{k =\max(0,n)}^\infty \frac{1}{k!(k-n)!}$$